# How to prove that there exists a constant C such that $\max |f|^{2} \le C \int \left ( |f'|^{2} + f^{2} \right ) dx$?

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-inequality

There is an inequality used in the paper written by Gage and Hamilton, but I am not sure how it comes. It states that there exists a constant $C$ such that on an interval $I$

$\max |f|^{2} \le C \int_{I} \left ( |f'|^{2} + f^{2} \right ) dx$

where $f(x)$ may not be continuous on $I$.

Comment: You should specify the domain of $f$ and other properties, like continuity, differentiability, etc

Comment: Thanks for reminding me

Comment: I guess it is fine as we can use improper integral although there may exist some points where $f^{\prime}$ does not exist.

Comment: @ZacharySelk : It's probably the weak derivative. The inequality is  probably $\|f\|_\infty \leq C \|f\|_{H^1}$, and that make perfect sense in the Sobolev spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is intended is surely some version of an instance of a Sobolev imbedding theorem, namely, that in one dimension the $H^1$ norm dominates the sup-norm. It suffices to prove this on test functions, where the derivative is literal, since test functions are dense in both. Then the sense of $f'$ has to be extended to the $L^2$ sense for it to make sense for $f$ not necessarily classically differentiable.

In that vein, by the contrapositive, if $f$ is not continuous, it cannot lie in $H^1$, so the right-hand side is $+\infty$ under any reasonable interpretation. So the inequality is vacuously true in that case.

Comment: In a very funny way you are the author of the paper I just cited...

Comment: @JeanMarie, and thus I can confidently endorse your answer! :)

Comment: I recognize there british fair play and humor.

Comment: It seems that the paper is a bit difficult for me as I know nothing about the Sobolev space, but at least I know where the inequality comes. Thank you!

Comment: @Brady, there is no need to go into great generalities... as in that note, the idea is basically calculus, together with Cauchy-Schwarz-Bunyakowsky inequality. Very basic calculus!!! Don't over-estimate the fanciness of the idea...

Comment: I was scared by some notation which I've never seen before, but I understand now! Thanks for showing me such an elegant proof!

Comment: @paul garrett I thought all the day at the coincidence of me finding a paper of you (without knowing you were looking at the very same issue), and you at the same time looking at this issue. What kind of probability could be attributed to this event ? Very very small...

Comment: @JeanMarie, small, but non-trivial, since now the internet "reduces friction". That is, people with common interests have less distance between... so it is not so much of a coincidence to find ourselves in the same "location". But/and, yes, this is wildly different from the 1970s and 1980s, prior to serious internet, when to communicate by ordinary post/mail would take about one week either way. There was no general way to "post" anything. Formal journals were the only possibility to communicate... [cont'd]

Comment: ... [cont'd] When it became clear that at least most universities in first-world countries would have access to "the internet" (c. 1995?), this seemed to me a "whole new world"... and, since I already had a reasonably secure situation, I thought to move into that new world, and disregard old traditions, and try to "explain to anyone who cared" whatever I had understood, after some time of thinking... It does console me that people are benefited by my on-line essays... despite the fact that my math dept does not count any such thing as "research". Nevermind... :)

Comment: @paul garrett Thank you for your interesting answer. I see we are on the same lines of thought. As a now retired professor (in France), I am fascinated as you are by the new communication means and try to use them in order to share my little part of knowledge in Mathematics with people, young and less young... :)

Comment: @JeanMarie :)   ....

Answer (score 1):

In fact your question deals with Sobolev space $H^1$. Have a look at the proof of Theorem of Rellich-Kondrachev [in this paper](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/simplest_cptness.pdf).